# MariaDB неправильное вычисление

Tags: mariadb

Подскажите пожалуйста в последней версии MariaDB проводится не правильное вычисления. К примеру если я выполню код:
SELECT (100/2592000*2585438);
То результат будет почему-то 0.00000
Хотя на старой mysql выполняя тот же самый код - результат правильный:
99.7462

Comment: Не почему-то, а по вполне понятной причине - контекст выполнения целочисленный, а совсем даже не с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а есть ли этому решение без редактирования SQL запроса? Так как другие похожие запросы тоже будут выводить уже не правильный результат.

Comment: *результат правильный: 99.7462* Неправильный. Вернее, неточный. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=350a5d6dea5454833f5a80110cdff0f8). Кстати, а какая ТОЧНО у Вас версия? потому как именно показанное выражение на fiddle вычисляется как DECIMAL на всех доступных там версиях. В соответствии с [Rules for Conversion on Dyadic Arithmetic Operations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/#rules-for-conversion-on-dyadic-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1